# MySql 5.6 Group Then Loop Thru Each Group

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, group-by

So am working with a special code where I need to GROUP BY *this*, then echo each item in each resulting group.

```
SELECT * FROM `geo` GROUP BY city ORDER BY visaid DESC"
```

From here, I get lost. Tried using:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(city) FROM `geo` GROUP BY city ORDER BY visaid DESC
```

It does not return *each*, but rather the count total for each group.
However, need to loop through the clustered results and display each row for each group. Example:

```
NEW YORK
    Brad, visaid, expired
    Gina, visaid, 1 month
    Sam, visaid, 1 week

LONDON
    Edward
    Patricia
```

How is this accomplished without running multiple queries?

Comment: that's what `group by` does. any records in a group become "collapsed" down into a new singular record. you can't get both a grouped-count AND the original ungrouped records in the same query.

Comment: Right. my original approach was to get the city count -which is needed- then run a secondary query for that city. But am looking for a simpler method. Given your reply, it seems such a task is not possible.

Comment: Was my answer able to solve your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/34800100/3822464

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged your question as PHP, you can use PHP to help with this.

Instead of using `GROUP BY`, just do `ORDER BY city, visaid DESC` and then as you go through the results have a variable that keeps track of the last row's city and when it differs from the current row's city, echo out the city name.

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved**

For anyone interested, I managed to use a single re-query to achieve the desired results.

```
SELECT * FROM `geo` GROUP BY city
```

Then a 2nd query

```
SELECT * FROM `geo` WHERE city='' ORDER BY visaid DESC
```